# Why does Xcode not display images when in fullscreen mode?

Tags: xcode, image, fullscreen, preview

I know this is not a serious deal breaker, but it annoys me almost daily:

The moment I switch my Xcode to fullscreen mode, I can’t preview any .png images from my project. I have to leave fullscreen to have a look at the images and icons.

I’m using Version 5.0.2 (5A3005) and can reproduce it on 3 Macs. Do you have a fix for this? The workaround of switching out of fullscreen and back is not tragic, but annoying.

Comment: Make sure to open a bug report.

Comment: Just tried this and get the same error. I never noticed it before because I never use fullscreen mode. Anyway, looks like a bug in Xcode...